# what's should i return when i invoke OnFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange() function

Tags: android, return

```
myEdit1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                myEdit2.setText("");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

`return false`, everything goes well. but if i change to `return true`, then there's something not in harmony.i cannot delete characters, nor use backspace key.i want to know that, in which situation should i `return true` or `return false`?
Any help appreciated. some examples better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Return true` to prevent this event from being propagated further, or `false` to indicate that you have not handled this event and it should continue to be propagated.

- **Return True:** Always return true if you have handled the event. And do not want that OS do something extra.
- **Return false:** Return false, if you did not handled the event and want OS to handle it.

In your case when you `return true`, default behavior of event is not executed as the event is not propagated further. It considers that you have handled the event. When you `return false`, the event is propagated further and performs default behavior. Because `false` indicates that  you have not handled the event